# Character escape \t in terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to run the following command in the terminal:

```
bet "C:\Users\user\Jupyter\Data\PROGRESSION\0012\t1ce_isotropic.nii.gz" "C:\Users\user\Jupyter\Data\PROGRESSION\0012\fet_brain.nii.gz" -R -f 0.3 -o -m
```

But I get the following error

```
Error: input image C:\Users\kated\Jupyter\ThesisData\PROGRESSION 1ce_isotropic not valid
```

A little research showed that using single quotes here should do the trick (since I have no other single quotes in my string), but after changing to single quotes, the same error persists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What operating system are you using? Is this on Windows? What shell?

Comment: Seems an issue in the program you're using, the shell does not convert `\t to tab.

Comment: Just for clarity, are you running Fsl in Windows Susbsytem for Linux (WSL) and trying to process files in the host Windows filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you posted this in AskUbuntu, I'm going to assume you are running Ubuntu, not Windows.

In Ubuntu, the path separator character is `/` not `\` and `\` is an escape character. I suggest you try replacing all the `\` characters with `/` and see if that helps.  Ironically, this would probably work in Windows too.

Comment: I can't think of any context where `'\t'` would behave differently from `"\t"`. What cases are you thinking of?

Comment: I'm thinking that single vs. double quotes is not the issue and that the invalid input image error is actually a file not found error because it can't find a file with that name when it should be a path.

Comment: OK, I removed the bit about how single quotes would stop `\ ` from being treated as an escape character.

Comment: I seem to remember in some shell the quote type made a difference, but not bash apparently.

Comment: Not for this. Perhaps you're thinking of ANSI escaping? For example `echo $'\t'` will print a tab but `echo $"\t"` will print a literal `\t`. But that is a different thing, and requires the `$` to be there too. There are some other corner cases as well like `echo 'foo\$bar'` vs `echo "$foo\$bar"` but that only applies when the `\ ` is followed by one of `$`, `\` `, `"`. `\ ` or a newline. I don't think there's any case or shell where `'\t'` and `"\t"` would be different.